# Custom order in SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently it coming in

```
G8984 - Carrying, Moving & Handling Objects - Current (CJ) 20 – 39% Impaired.
G8985 - Carrying, Moving & Handling Objects - Projected (CI) 1 – 19% Impaired.
G8985 - Carrying, Moving & Handling Objects - Projected (CI) 1 – 19% Impaired.
G8986 - Carrying, Moving & Handling Objects - Discharge (CL) 60 – 79% Impaired.
```

Reuirement is :

```
G8986 - Carrying, Moving & Handling Objects - Discharge (CL) 60 – 79% Impaired.
G8984 - Carrying, Moving & Handling Objects - Current (CJ) 20 – 39% Impaired.
G8985 - Carrying, Moving & Handling Objects - Projected (CI) 1 – 19% Impaired.
G8985 - Carrying, Moving & Handling Objects - Projected (CI) 1 – 19% Impaired.
```

It's like I need order in 
Discharge need to come first, then Current, then Projected

This string I am creating using this below code:

```
,(LT.[Code] + ' - ' + LFLC.[Description] + ' - ' + LFLT.[Description] + ' (' + LM.[Code] + ') ' + LM.[ShortName]) AS [Description]
```

Table LFLT is:

[image]

Comment: Is that one or several columns?

Comment: Describe how to order!

Comment: Please read how to ask a question. As its stands, this is a very poor quality question. With no column names, table structure, it would be very hard for anyone to help you out.

Comment: This is multiple rows

Comment: We can see it's multiple rows, but we have no idea of your schema, or your query, or anything else for that matter

Comment: All other column data is same that's why I didn't give Column or Schema names

Comment: It is I need a order by B,A,C,D not in A,B,C,D or D,C,B,A                                   Discharge need to come first, then Current, then Projected

Comment: @RakeshPattanayak What is `LM.Code` OR `LT.Code`? can't you order by those columns

Comment: LM.Code or LT.Code come same value & Different as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT ..., CASE WHEN LFLT.ID = 3 THEN 0 ELSE LFLT.ID END AS OrderIndex
FROM ...
ORDER BY OrderIndex
```

Comment: We are really superb, You suggested the correct thing.